# Run a service after installation using Orca

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, orca

How to run a specific service after end of msi installation using Orca? I know I need to set up Custom Action but I totally cannot figure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom action at all, you need rows in the [ServiceInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371637(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ServiceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371634(v=vs.85).aspx) tables.  FWIW, very few people actually use ORCA to author MSIs. It's more of a tool to examine MSIs and occasionally create transforms.  Most setup developers use other tools such as [Windows Installer XML](http://wixtoolset.org/) to author source code that gets built into an MSI.  In that scenario you use [ServiceInstall](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html) and [ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html) elements to tell the compiler to author rows into those tables in the MSI.

I maintain an open source project for WiX called [IsWiX](https://iswix.codeplex.com/).  IsWiX consists of Visual Studio project templates that act as scaffolding for an installer.  It also provides graphical UI's for authoring most of your installer logic including support for directories, files (components) and services.   WiX supports MSBuild / TFS making automated CI builds of MSIs a piece of cake.

I have a video on youtube: [Building and Deploying a Windows Service using IsWiX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJxU47_zqbw) that shows the process using Visual Studio Online for source / build automation.  It's a little out of date as in the video I show authoring the ServiceInstall / ServiceControl elements by hand but in the latest release of IsWiX that can be done graphically using the new Services designer.

Comment: Thanks for this but I need it for Orca. That I don't need Custom Action could move me forward though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a VS setup project then the answer would be that you're already installing the service with an installer class custom action, so you override the Install method, call base.Install() and then add your code to actually start the service.

That's the VS setup project way, in spite of the support that Windows Installer provides, as Christopher mentions.

This might help if you want to use Visual Studio setups and use the standard way to control services:

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/tips.htm

and scroll down to Installing Services in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks but events from VS doesn't work for me during the updates from any reason.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but people routinely create custom action code to start their services in VS setups, so if that's what you've tried it may just be something in your code.